# Can we define a custom array as a Mongoose schema type?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

## Mongoose Schema Type

> define the role array in a new file,
>   use that role module as a schema type when defining a new schema

```
//define this role array 
   exports.module = {
        role:['admin','consumer','super_admin']
    };

//can we use the above role array as a schema type when defining schema
    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type:String,
        required:true
      },
      profilePic:String,
      email:{
        type:String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        required:true
      },
      role:{
        type: [userRole.module.role],
        required:true
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find answer on either

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html
- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html

Answer (score 1):

From the mongoose docs:

```js
const ToySchema = new Schema({ name: String });

const ToyBoxSchema = new Schema({
  toys: [ToySchema], // <== used here
  buffers: [Buffer],
  strings: [String],
  numbers: [Number]
  // ... etc
});
```

Source: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays

Answer (score 0):

To create a new schema type, you need to inherit from mongoose.SchemaType and add the corresponding property to mongoose. For creating your custom schema type follow this link :

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html